# Freeform File Uploads with Multi-site Manager

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads, multi-site-manager

I'm running EE 5.3.2 with Freeform Lite 1.8.3. I have the multi-site manager setup with 2 sites, we'll call them Site A & Site B.

Site B has a form that allows for a file upload. When a file is uploaded through the form, the file does get uploaded and the form seems to work correctly but I'm unable to show file information for the upload in the Freeform notifications.

I verified that the files are being uploaded to the correct directory in Site B's file structure and the files show up in the file manager in the correct directory. But when I try to edit the file or download it in the file manager, EE gives me the following error: Error: No file selected.

If I switch over to Site A and go to the file manager, the uploaded file shows up there are well for some reason and I am able to edit and download it there. But the file does not appear in any directory in the file manager and it does not exist on the server in Site A's file structure.

Somewhere the lines are getting crossed and I can't figure out where.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a known issue between Freeform and MSM, and Solspace does not currently have a solution. Freeform isn't completely compatible with MSM although it works just fine until you need a form with file uploads.